# Non-trvial groupby is slow in Pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

There's a ton of slow Pandas groupby posts but all of them seem to be different in some way and it's not obvious how I would translate it to my problem.

Let's start with a simple version of the problem that I can solve and then build up from there.

(1) Bin time-series data by summing `col1` every 5 time stamps and create ohlc bars:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

# set seed in case reproducability becomes useful in the future
random.seed(13)

# create a weeks worth time points 
# NOTE: this is evenly spaced but in real life is not (I can change make this more realistic if someone thinks it's important)
periods = 7 * 24 * 60
time_range = pd.date_range('2016-07-01', periods=periods, freq='T')
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [random.random() for _ in range(len(time_range))], 'col2': [random.randint(1, 10) * random.random() for _ in range(len(time_range))]}, index = time_range)

# pandas has some great methods that do things really fast. For example grouping every 5 time stamps and putting into ohlc bars can be done with
df.reset_index(inplace = True)
print(df.head())
df['col1'].groupby(df.index // 5).ohlc()
```

(2) What if I wanted to add two columns so that we know the start and end time of each bar?

(3) Furthermore, what if we wanted to group by more complex functions? For example is there a fast way to create ohlc bars for col1 such that each bar contains the minimum amount of time stamps such that the sum of col1 * col2 >= 10? We also want to know the open and close stamp too.

Here's my working (but very slow attempt):

```
# We start by looking for the smallest range of indexes that meets the condition  
base_idx = df.index[0] # start the range at the beginning of the DF
group_counter = 1 # all the ranges need to be given group numbers so that it can be grouped at the end 
group_column = [0 for idx in df.index] # this column will be added to the DF at the end indicating which row belongs to which group
group_count_to_start_and_end_date_dict = {} # this takes a group number as a key and returns the open and close time stamp for that group
for idx in df.index: # loop through all indexes
    if idx == df.index[-1]: #if idx made it to the end of the DF then just put it all together into the final group even if it it doesn't meet the condition to make a group
        group_column[base_idx:idx + 1] = [group_counter] * len(group_column[base_idx:idx + 1]) 
        group_count_to_start_and_end_date_dict[group_counter] = [df.loc[base_idx, 'index'], df.loc[idx, 'index']]
    elif (df.loc[base_idx:idx,'col2'] * df.loc[base_idx:idx, 'col1']).sum() >= 10: # if the grouping conidtion is met then add the new group 
        group_column[base_idx:idx] = [group_counter] * len(group_column[base_idx:idx])
        group_count_to_start_and_end_date_dict[group_counter] = [df.loc[base_idx, 'index'], df.loc[idx, 'index']]
        base_idx = idx # start a new range
        group_counter += 1 # start a new group

df['groupings'] = group_column # add groupings colun to the df
# perform group by and create ohlc bars 
grouped1 = df.groupby('groupings')
grouped = grouped1.col1.ohlc()
# add the open and close time stamps for each bar
grouped['open_stamp'] = grouped.index.map(lambda x: group_count_to_start_and_end_date_dict[x][0])
grouped['close_stamp'] = grouped.index.map(lambda x: group_count_to_start_and_end_date_dict[x][1])
```

Can anyone help me increase the performance of this?

Comment: I wonder, in a group X, do you want to include the row when the cumulative sum get above 10 or you want to include this row in the following group. I ask because slicing `base_idx:idx` does not include the row `idx`?

Answer (score 1):

you can create the column groupings using `cumsum` on the multiplication of both column  and then array manipulations to remove the value once above 10 and restart the cumulative sum such as:

```
#need these 2 arrays for the calculation
arr_mult = (df.col1*df.col2).values
arr = arr_mult.cumsum().copy() 

gr = np.zeros_like(arr)
for i in range(len(arr)-1):
    if arr[i] >= 10:
        # recalculated the rest of the array once above 10
        arr[i:] -= arr[i] - arr_mult[i]
        # put one where a new group should start
        gr[i] = 1

df['groupings'] = gr.cumsum() + 1
```

Then to get the result, you can concat the ohlc of col1 and use first and last on the column index:

```
grouped = pd.concat([ df.groupby('groupings').col1.ohlc(), 
                      df.groupby('groupings').index.agg(['first', 'last'])], axis=1)\
            .rename(columns = {'first': 'open_stamp','last': 'close_stamp'})

print (grouped.head())
               open      high       low     close          open_stamp  \
groupings                                                               
1.0        0.259008  0.685258  0.259008  0.684082 2016-07-01 00:00:00   
2.0        0.849336  0.849336  0.147160  0.225163 2016-07-01 00:03:00   
3.0        0.734024  0.837657  0.014432  0.014432 2016-07-01 00:08:00   
4.0        0.275837  0.949323  0.146710  0.256708 2016-07-01 00:17:00   
5.0        0.849939  0.849939  0.486785  0.486785 2016-07-01 00:27:00   

                  close_stamp  
groupings                      
1.0       2016-07-01 00:02:00  
2.0       2016-07-01 00:07:00  
3.0       2016-07-01 00:16:00  
4.0       2016-07-01 00:26:00  
5.0       2016-07-01 00:28:00
```

Note with your code, what you called close_stamp is actually the open_stamp of the next group, while I assumed you wanted the last stamp of the current group that this code get. I think it should be more efficient than your code